# Example = PHPmailer sending Form <form>, with Email, with several attachments, from several inputs[file]. Example for upgrade

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer, attachment

I would like to show you, my custom functions working with PHPmailer function, which I use for sending email with (always) three attachments from three inputs.

I would like to ask you, is possible to upgrade this tone of code for better? I am front-end and PHP is a new great challenge to me.

PS. I hope this post will help someone, for customize, you need to paste your `$filePath` variable in `saveFile` function and arrays with inputs.

Whole function creates randomHash and concate it to `$_FILES[input-name][name]`, after that file is moved to new ./uploads directory. Save new patch with [name] to global array `$patch`. Function `checkData` check filetypes. After that `global $patch` serves patches for files to attach them like mail attachments in `sendMail()` function.

```
<?php 
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}

function checkData()
{
$typeArray = [ $_FILES['file_one']['type'], $_FILES['file_two']['type'], $_FILES['file_three']['type'] ];

foreach ($typeArray as $key) {
    if ($key != 'image/jpeg' && $key != 'application/msword' && $key != 'image/png' && $key != 'application/pdf' && $key != 'application/zip') 
    {
        echo "File is incorrect!";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        echo "File is correct!";
    }
}
return true;
}

function saveFile()
{
if(checkData() == true)
{
    global $patch;
    $patch = array();
    $multiArray = 
    [
        [$_FILES['file_one']['name'], $_FILES['file_one']['tmp_name']],
        [$_FILES['file_two']['name'], $_FILES['file_two']['tmp_name']],
        [$_FILES['file_three']['name'], $_FILES['file_three']['tmp_name']]
    ];

    foreach ($multiArray as $key) 
    {
        echo "<br />Key: ".$key[0]."\n";
        echo "Key_tmp: ".$key[1]."\n";


        $randomString = generateRandomString();
        $patchFile = './uploads/'.$randomString.$key[0];

        echo "<br />Check patchFile: $patchFile";

        if(is_uploaded_file($key[1]))
        {
            echo "<br />Begin uploading to directory...<br />";
            if(!move_uploaded_file($key[1], $patchFile))
            {
                echo 'Trouble with copy file to uploads directory.';
                return false;  
            }
            else {
                echo "File was saved in uploads directory";
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Uploading to directory... FAILED!";
            return false; 
        }

        array_push($patch, $patchFile);
    }
    var_dump($patch);
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo "File format was incorrect.";
    return false;
}
}

function sendMail() {

    if(saveFile() == true)
    {
        global $patch;

        echo "Check $patch variable:<br />";
        var_dump($patch);

        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $email      = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $borrowman  = $_REQUEST['borrowman'];
        $lendman    = $_REQUEST['lendman'];
        $cash       = $_REQUEST['cash'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main SMTP server. If you dont have one us GMAL or mandrill
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'XXXXX';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'XXXXX';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->setFrom($email, 'Zgłoszenie Nakaz');
        $mail->addAddress('lechowski.g@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('lechowski.g@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('lechowski.g@gmail.com', 'Information');
        $mail->addCC('lechowski.g@gmail.com');
        $mail->addBCC('lechowski.g@gmail.com');

        foreach ($patch as $attachment) {
            $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
        }

        #$mail->addAttachment($patchFile);                      // Add attachments
        #$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');     // Optional name
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                    // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = 'Zgłoszenie - Nakaz Windykacyjny';
        $mail->Body    = '<h3>Nakaz Windykacyjny<h3><br />Wierzyciel: '.$borrowman.'<br />Email: '.$email.'<br />Dłużnik: '.$lendman.'<br />Kwota: '.$cash;
        $mail->AltBody = 'Nakaz Windykacyjny Wierzyciel: '.$borrowman.'Email: '.$email.'Dłużnik: '.$lendman.'Kwota: '.$cash;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Message was not sended, some problem with files was detected.";
    }
}

sendMail();
?>
```

Comment: That code looks ok, not bad if you're new to PHP. You should edit out your password though. Adding the same address more than once isn't likely to work. Is there a problem with the code, or are you just after opinions?

Comment: Damn, I forgot hide pass and mail... Thanks for warm words!:) Everything works fine, but I wondering about some upgrade/mashup.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `input_filter` function instead of `$_REQUEST` - much safer thing to do. It looks like this: `input_filer(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

More on the topic you can find here: http://www.sitepoint.com/input-validation-using-filter-functions

In `$mail->AltBody` you probably want to add some `PHP_EOL` to break it into lines.

You can also think about using `sprintf` to achieve more readable code:

```
sprints('
    <h3>Nakaz Windykacyjny<h3><br />
    Wierzyciel: %s<br />
    Email: %s<br />Dłużnik: %s<br />
    Kwota: %d',

    $borrowman,
    $email,
    $lendman
)
```